# Powershell window height collapsing

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-10-v1607

Using Windows 10, new command prompt, occasionally my window height collapses such that only the title bar is visible. Maximizing/restoring has no impact on this, and it stays shrunken even if maximized. The only way I can bring it back is to use the mouse and drag the window back down.

I assume I'm fat-fingering some keyboard shortcut, but I'm not sure what. Not sure if its powershell only, or if it would happen with a regular cmd, since I only do it accidentally. How am I causing this and how can I disable or revert it?

I'm not running any third party window managers. I do use Synergy.

Comment: What happens when docking the windows to a side via [Windows]+[Left-/Right-Arow]?

Comment: happened to me to in the past (not on Windows anymore) - what I did was resize the window (not maximize/restore) and then closed it (to save the size) and opened again. What made it zero row height - I never figured it out. Synergy should not be the problem (was using it too).

Comment: @LotPings I'll have to give that a try next time it happens.